# Rails 4 x Bootstrap 3: how to generate an error alert in view from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, alert

I am using Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3 to build a CRUD web app.

I have an Invite model that lets users invite other users to join the app — and this is currently working.

This is my `InvitesController`:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # some code
    if @invite.save
      # some code
      redirect_to some_path, notice: 'Invitation was successfully sent.'
    else
      redirect_to another_path, alert: 'Invitation could not be sent: please make sure you enter a valid email address and choose a role.'
    end
  end

end
```

Now, when a user successfully sends an invite, he is redirected to some path and gets a ***blue*** `notice` telling him precisely that.

However, when a user does not fill the Invite form correctly and the invite cannot be sent successfully, he is redirected to the same view (where the form is) and gets a ***yellow*** `alert` telling him there was an error in his form.

I would like to make the latter a ***red*** `alert` and I thought Bootstrap would allow me to do so by using `redirect_to another_path, error: 'Invitation could not be sent: please make sure you enter a valid email address and choose a role.'`

This did not work.

–––––

**UPDATE**: What I am looking for here is a way to use the `.alert-danger` Bootstrap alert class, I don't want to simply change the color of my alert from yellow to red.

–––––

What is the Rails / Bootstrap way of achieving what I need?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/jzofog/ruby-on-rails-flash-messages-with-bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem there is a great helper already available for you to use that pretty much handles what you already have in place.

#### Gemfile

`gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'`

#### application.html.erb

`<%= bootstrap_flash %>`

The `bootstrap_flash` method is used inside your views and is where the flash will display. I prefer to put mine inside the application.html.erb file as it is used across *most* of my pages. Furthermore, this method pretty much does what Moustafa posted except the gem creator just did it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way I accomplish this:

First I create a `helper method` to translate the `flash message type` into `bootstrap type`

```
def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
  case flash_type.to_sym
    when :success
      "alert-success"
    when :error
      "alert-danger"
    when :alert
      "alert-warning"
    when :notice
      "alert-info"
    else
      flash_type.to_s
    end
end
```

Then I create a partial to render the messages stored in the flash session according to its type.

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <div class="alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(type) %> fade in">
   <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
   <%= message.html_safe %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```